# Strategy for choosing the number of optimizer runs for factory contracts

Tags: solidity, contract-development, optimization, factory

The number of optimizer runs in Solidity should normally be set to the expected number of times the contract will be called in its lifetime. To quote the [Solidity docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.18/internals/optimizer.html#optimizer-parameter-runs):

> The number of runs (`--optimizer-runs`) specifies roughly how often each opcode of the deployed code will be executed across the life-time of the contract.

However, does this rule apply even to factory contracts, which can create other contracts?

The factory contract itself will be called many times, but the deployed contract may be called significantly less often.